# Using animation (HTML5 Canvas Document) in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to use 3 different animations within a slideshow. For the slideshow I used the `uikit` (front-end framework developed in LESS & SASS based on html, css, javascript and jQuery) and I embedded the animations which were created in Adobe Animate CC in an iframe.

Everything works perfect, but the problem is that all 3 animations are loading on the same time. Because all of them include sound elements I can hear 3 different sounds while only the first animation is visible.
Is it possible to define something for the animations itself that the animation timeline starts playing only when the animation is visible?

Let me show a code snippet, maybe this will explain my problem:

Codesnippet

[image]

This is the first coding part of the slideshow. The file 'slide01.html' is the first animation, which is displayed to the user directly. Further in the code there is also a `slide02.html` and `slide03.html` which are also animations. So I did not build a whole slideshow in Adobe Animate CC, but I created 3 different animations, which are implemented separately. So there are 3 different html files within an iframe, which starts playing once the whole website is completely loaded.

Comment: Please include code within your question instead of at the other end of links. That image contains only HTML. Where's the jQuery you're using?

Comment: I uploaded one of the animation with all files into a .zip file (www.adconcept.de/upload/Manni%20Hula.zip). Maybe this helps. Otherwise I am currently working on a test site where I will include the animation – once I am done I will post the URL here maybe this will also help. I think that somehow I have to restrict that animation 2 and 3 load on page load and then include some code that the first animation stops after the slide is changing to the second animation, which should be played then and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create Animation using Java Script

```js
function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (pos == 350) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
            elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#myAnimation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>
<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button> 
</p>

<div id ="myContainer">
<div id ="myAnimation"></div>
</div>

<script>
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```